# UICollectionView cell disappears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using collectionView in my iPad application. I have used custom layout class which inherited UICollectionViewFlowLayout class.

I am using horizontal scroll directional. The problem is, whenever we use scroll for collection view, some times cell get disappear. I debugged the code, and found that in data source method after creating cell, its hidden property get automatically ON.

I tried using below line but its not working

```
   cell.hidden = NO
```

I have below method also to invalidate layout on bound change.

```
    - (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
          return YES;
        }
```

But still I am facing problem. Any solution on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: same issue is happening for me also, did u figure out a solution?

Comment: I managed to fix my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913664/uicollectionviewcell-gets-hidden-randomly/38931405#38931405

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue which may cause cells to [disappear](https://openradar.appspot.com/12433891) in UICollectionView. If their fix doesn't work for you, try [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView), 
which is an open source replacement for UICollectionView. If PSTCollectionView works, you should file a radar ticket to Apple.

Comment: you mean to say this is UICollectionView bug?

Comment: I encountered quite a few bugs with UICollectionView recently. I am pretty sure that UICollectionView is not bug-free. The best way to check is to use PSTCollectionView. Since it is open source, you can trace your code easily.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, the UICollectionViewCell disappear also ,the flowLayout i use is a custom layout named `UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout` . Its scroll direction is horizontal .I debug the project again and again, have tried every solution i can find through `google.com`. All that did not work for me.

At the end ,i delete the `UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout` and use native 
`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` through:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout   = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

layout.scrollDirection               = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
_collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
_CollectionView.autoresizingMask     = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

And I set the cell spacing through storyboard（also you can set them through the layout's propery）:

[image: spacing]

Then i run the project again , the UICollectionViewCell DO NOT DISAPPEAR anymore. Hope my case can help you .