# UICollectionViewCell gets hidden randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UIView in which I am adding a `UICollectionView` to act as a banner view to look like a carousel. The `Viewcontroller` in which `UIView` is present, is part of `pageviewcontroller`.

PageVC --> `UIViewController` --> `UIView` --> `UICollectionView`.

Each VC has its own banner, so when the page is swiped, I reload the `collectionView` with the respective data and I am able to see it. Now if visit a page which I already visited, the `collectionview` cell disappears. The `collectionview` is visible but the cell is somehow hidden.

The `collectionview` cell is a customcell and I am not using any custom layout, I am using the default `flowlayout`. This is working fine in `iOS8-devices`.

Below is the debugger output,
When cell is visible:

```
CollectionViewCell: 0x7f9db8d9ffa0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (209 3.5; 209 96); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9dbb5dde60>>
```

When invisible (you can see its hidden now) the dequed cell is now hidden, no clue why it is happening

```
CollectionViewCell: 0x7f9dbb5897e0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 3.5; 209 96); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9dbb590220>>
```

**indexPathsForVisibleItems** is returning nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was calling `reloadData` from multiple places which caused the system to get confused (may be) especially I have written `reloadData` in my `updateconstraints` method and hence for each minor constraint change `reloadData` was getting called.

Check all places from where you call `reloadData` for `collectionview` if you're experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem.

After

- checking if the **UICollectionView reloadData** was called in some thread other than the MainThread
- checking if there is any cases about multi-calling **reloadData** or **updateconstraints**

without solving my problem, I realized that in some occasions **CGSizeZero** was returned for **collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:**.

When avoiding the CGSizeZero result, everything works well.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem.

Here's my situation:

My collection view has a custom layout. I use the default flow layout without any problem.

When I use my custom layout, whose cell width is a half screen width. When I scroll to the 5th cell, all cells became hidden without reason.

Finally I found out that when I **set cell's size correctly in the layout class** of the storyboard, the problem is resolved.

Hope this helps.