# UICollectionView dequeues hidden cells when paging is enabled

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

When paging is enabled a `UICollectionView` dequeues only 3 cells and the rest of the cells are dequeued as hidden for no reason. Perhaps, it is the way how `UICollectionView` works in general, but in my project I really need that every time a cell is dequeued `cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath method` is called it actually creates a non-hidden instance of a custom `UICollectionViewCell`.

Maybe, it only creates 3 instances because it needs to manage the memory correctly. However, in my project a custom `UICollectionViewCell` also contains a another `collectionView` which consists of 3 custom `collectionView` cells. These `collectionView` cells also have `tableViews` inside of them the data of which is encapsulated in these cells. My main questions are: why does a `UICollectionView` only creates 3 instances in my case and what can I do to avoid this behavior?

The hierarchy in my actual project looks like this: `UICollectionView` -> `UICollectionView` -> 3 custom `UICollectionViewCell` -> each `UICollectionViewCell` contains a `tableView` -> each `tableView` contains a specific custom `TableViewCell`.

Here is the whole code that I wrote in as an example of what’s going in my actual project (this is not the actual project, but the behavior is the same):

`ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let cellId = "uniqueCellId"
    let sampleWords: [String] = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
    let colors: [UIColor] = [.green, .yellow, .blue, .purple, .gray, .red]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        registerCollectionViewCustomCell()
        prepareUI()
        setupViews()
        setCollectionViewLayoutToHorizontal()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    //collectionView is instantiated as a computed property. Initialized with a system flow layout. The frame is initially assigned to CGRect.zero because it is controlled by the constrains
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        cv.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        cv.isPagingEnabled = true
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        return cv
    }()
}
```

Extension 1

```
extension ViewController {
    private func prepareUI() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
        navigationItem.title = "Collection View"
    }

    private func registerCollectionViewCustomCell() {
        collectionView.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    private func setCollectionViewLayoutToHorizontal() {
        if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        }
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-15-[v0]-15-|", views: collectionView)
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-80-[v0]-140-|", views: collectionView)

    }
}
```

Extension 2:

```
//configuring the dataSource and the delegate methods for the collectionView
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.item]
        cell.wordLabel.text = sampleWords[indexPath.item]
        print("_____________________________________")
        print(cell.isHidden)
        if cell.isHidden {
            print("CUSTOM CELL INSTANCE NOT CREATED")
        }
        print("_____________________________________")
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sampleWords.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
        return size
    }
}
```

`CustomCollectionViewCell` class:

```
//custom cell class
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        print("instance of CustomCollectionViewCell is created")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let wordLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    private func setupViews() {
        addSubview(wordLabel)

        wordLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: wordLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 70))
    }
}
```

Helper method addConstraintsWithFormat:

```
//helper method to add constraints to a view
extension UIView {
    func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...){
        var viewsDictionary = [String : UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
}
```

This is all the code that I have. Everything is done without a `storyboard` only programmatically.

To debug and to understand what’s going on for myself I’ve added a few print statements: 
1) “Print” statement that outputs the boolean value if a cell is hidden, and if a cell.isHidden -> true -> an instance of the custom `CollectionViewCell` has not been created.
2) “Print” statement within the custom `CollectionViewCell` class in the init method to see whether a cell has been created or not.

The output is always the following:

```
instance of CustomCollectionViewCell is created
______________________________________
false
______________________________________
instance of CustomCollectionViewCell is created
______________________________________
false
______________________________________
instance of CustomCollectionViewCell is created
______________________________________
false
______________________________________
______________________________________
true
CUSTOM CELL INSTANCE NOT CREATED
```

and after that the cell.Hidden always returns a true values.

I found that some people were struggling with the same problem. But the solutions did not help me. Because I don't use the method `collectionView.reloadData()` anywhere and I cannot change the size of a single cell.
[UICollectionViewCell gets hidden randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913664/uicollectionviewcell-gets-hidden-randomly)

Comment: Does it deque all the cells that are hidden or only some of them?

Comment: I'm not quite sure because as I scroll the pages I see in the output that after 3 created cells the rest of the cells are always hidden. It can infinitely dequeue the cells but only 3 instances are actually created. Maybe it only dequeues these 3 cells and then work with only those three throughout the whole UICollectionView. @Sandeep

Comment: I think it is normal if it creates few cells before hand. All it tries to do is optimize your scrolling behaviour, so in the process it might preload few cells. But, if it preloads all cells, then, that is a problem, which means either you are not dequeing properly or bug with apple(which I doubt)

Comment: Basic ideas of Collection view if reusing same cells  to improve performance and memory consumption. If you don't want to use this mechanism you can actually create cell each time. Please mind though that cell will be recreated each time you scroll. Regarding your code - you make quite widespread mistake misguiding view lifecycle. In case of cell it not recommended to do any layouts in init.`loadView` is specifically designated for these purpose. Regarding `isHidden` - it is normal collection view behaviour.

Comment: You mention desire to place other controllers inside your cell, and mentioned pages. It seems that CollectionView doesn't suit your intentions. Perhaps you should take a look on PageViewController.

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov, you are right, in my case it might be a good idea to use PageViewController instead. Right now I'm only using views in other views and eventually combine them all in one ViewController. And yes, I did layouts in the initializer of the cells too. Thank you for the advice in general and for the explanation on how a UICollectionView manages its cells.

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionView dequeues the cells that will be immediately visible on screen as `isHidden = false` and additional ones it is preparing that are offscreen as `isHidden = true`. This reflects the actual state that these cells will have when you view is displayed. You cannot override this behaviour nor the state of `isHidden` by setting `hidden = false`. This state automatically is updated by the UICollectionView as cells scroll into and out of view.

I have implemented a similar structure, where a UICollectionViewCell contains another UICollectionView. (One scrolling horizontally, the second vertically within that cell.) I can state categorically it is not necessary for a UICollectionView cell to have `isHidden = false` in order to correctly lay out subviews of the cell. It sounds like you're probably thinking that this hidden attribute is the cause of a problem you're having (I've been down that exact thought path) but you're actually wrong and the cause of the issue is something else.

In my case, for the record, the problem cells were reporting an auto layout constraint conflict, which I had been ignoring as I thought it was unrelated. The fix was that after I added the subview to my UICollectionViewCell, I needed to call `layoutSubviews()` on my cell view and `reloadData()` on the collection view it contained. If I did not do this, the embedded collections worked sometimes, but when it re-used previously created cells, rather than creating new ones, they would fail to display due to autolayout conflicts. This meant there were specific paths to get there that would or would not display the issue depending on what cells were created in previous views that were available for reuse.